# Maven resource filtering with Arquillian/ShrinkWrap

Tags: java, maven, jboss-arquillian, shrinkwrap

How to build Arquillian ShrinkWrap deployment that will execute Maven resource filtering? 
Which version of ShrinkWrap should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to information from ShrinkWrap developers https://community.jboss.org/message/781880#781880 this is not yet implemented.

The ticket for this feature https://issues.jboss.org/browse/SHRINKRES-100

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: see my other answer, this is actually implemented and simple to use ;-)

<strike>Grzegorz is correct, this isn't implemented in Arquillian.</strike>

As a workaround, I ended up with this in @Deployment:

```
Properties testProperties = new Properties();
ClassLoader contextClassLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream testPropertiesInputStream = contextClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("test.properties");
testProperties.load(testPropertiesInputStream);

File testPropertiesTargetFile = File.createTempFile("arquillian_test_", ".properties");
try (Writer testPropertiesWriter = Files.newBufferedWriter(testPropertiesTargetFile.toPath())) {
    testProperties.store(testPropertiesWriter, null);
}
webArchive.addAsResource(testPropertiesTargetFile, "test.properties");
```

And this in @Setup:

```
private Properties testProperties;

@Before
public void setUp() throws IOException {
    testProperties = new Properties();
    InputStream testPropertiesInputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/test.properties");
    testProperties.load(testPropertiesInputStream);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying to "fix" it, it turns out the answer is quite simple...

```
    webArchive.addAsResource("test.properties");
```

... will use a classpath resource that maven has already filtered.

Comment: ... and just add a <testResource> element in your pom.xml with <filtering>true</filtering> if you haven't already done so.